# JScrollPane Not Updating Correctly

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

My JScrollPane isn't updating correctly.

```
    public static JScrollPane scrollPane;
public static List<String> usernames = new ArrayList<String>();
public static JList list;

    public static void getUsername() {
    usernames.add(Frame.username);
    list = new JList(usernames.toArray());
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);

    // Update
    scrollPane.revalidate();
    list.revalidate();
    panel.revalidate();

    frame.repaint();
    System.out.println("user connected");
}
```

I've tried repaint(), revalidate(), and validate() on the scrollpane, the jlist, the panel, and the frame and the scroll pane won't update.  It updates fine if I add a new scrollpane with the new data in the array.

```
        server.addListener(new Listener() {
        public void received(Connection connection, Object object) {
            new Run();
            players++;
            playerLabel.setText("Players currently online: " + players);
            getUsername();
        }
    });
```

Comment: It doesn't add the new data or you're can't scrolling?

Comment: It adds the new data, but it isn't showing visually in the JList/JScrollPane.

Answer (score 1):

when your'e adding new to your list , try to use

```
yourList.setListData(newData);
```

and add the list to the scrollpane

**UPDATE:**

```
DefaultListModel<String> model;

private void UpdateJList(){
    model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    for(Users u : list){
         model.addElement(u.ToString());
    }    
    theJList.setModel(model);     
    theJList.setSelectedIndex(0); // this will mark the first row (item) on the list
}
```

Comment: yourList would be my JList (list), but what about newData?  My array?  I'm not sure what parameter it would take.

Comment: I currently have this: `public static void getUsername() {
  usernames.add(Frame.username);
  list.setListData(usernames.toArray());
  scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
  
  frame.repaint();
 }`

Comment: what is userNames? I see that you're converting it to array.. 
but what lt's type?

Comment: oh i see -> you have arrayList <string> called userNames
and you add to this array a new user name right? 
now when you're doing this you need to set this array as the new data of the list.. so in your case 'yourList' is list and 'newData' is usernames

Comment: Exactly.  However when I used usernames as newData it threw an error. `The method setListData(Object[]) in the type JList is not applicable for the arguments (List<String>)` Because "usernames" is an arraylist like you said.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks man!  Really appreciate it :)  By the way, for anybody who needs it here is my code for my specific situation:

```
    public static void getUsername() {
    usernames.add(Frame.username);
    model = new DefaultListModel();
    model.addElement(usernames.toString());
    list.setModel(model);
    list.setSelectedIndex(0);
}
```

Comment: glad my answer helped you.. (you can accept it if you want :) )